# Can't parse json from Resources

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

In resources I have json file with next content:

```
{
"EU": [
    "Germany",
    "Ukraine",
    "United Kingdom",
    "Hungary"
 ]
}
```

I want to deserialize it into `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`

I've tried next :

```
var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Resources.regionGroups);//Resources.regionGroups return byte[]

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json);
```

But every time I get exception as variable `json` is in incorect json format.

What can cause this? I've tried the same deserialization but with jsonString as hard-coded and it works.

---

Detailed exception message :

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line
>   0, position 0.
>
> ---

UPDATE :

After removing all spaces

```
var json = Regex.Replace(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Resources.regionGroups), "(\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")|\\s+", "$1");
```

from string I have next one

```
"{\"EU\":[\"Germany\",\"Ukraine\",\"United Kingdom\",\"Hungary\"]}"
```

which also reproduce exception.

Comment: What is the value of `json` variable of `var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Resources.regionGroups);` in watch window?

Comment: @AdilAnsari , `"{\r\n\t\"EU\": [\r\n\t\t\"Germany\",\r\n\t\t\"Ukraine\",\r\n\t\t\"United Kingdom\",\r\n\t\t\"Hungary\"\r\n\t]\r\n}\r\n"`

Comment: **UPDATE:** `\r\n\t\`` are causing the problem, use `json.Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","").Replace("\t","").Replace("\","")` to remove these extra strings.

Comment: the problem might be related to `UTF8` encoding.Try `ASCII` or `Default`.

Comment: @AdilAnsari, character `\` I can't remove. Tried `Replace(@"\","")` and `Replace("\\","")` but no success )

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh , with another encoding is event worse

Comment: Try to execute the line without `Replace("\","")`. Your new code will be `json.Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","").Replace("\t","")`

Comment: The Json string itself deserializes fine

Comment: @AdilAnsari, nope, also still the same problem

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, than why it behaves in such way in my case?

Comment: I tried your code on my machine it is working. `string s = "{\"EU\":[\"Germany\",\"Ukraine\",\"United Kingdom\",\"Hungary\"]}";`
            `Dictionary<string, List<string>> deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(s);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well @AmitKumarGhosh was right about encoding, as I think.

So I've tried to change type of my json file in the Resources. I've changed it from binary to text file and this helps.

So parsing now is very simple :

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(Resources.regionGroups);
```